# How to draw multiple rectangles using c#

Tags: c#

I have drawn and saved the Rectangle on the image i loaded in the picture box. How i like to draw multiple rectangles for that i tried array in the rectangle but it gives error ("Object reference not set to an instance of an object." (Null reference Exception was unhandled).

```
private void pictureBox1_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    if (mybitmap == null)
    {
        mybitmap = new Bitmap(sz.Width, sz.Height);
    }
    rect[count] = new Rectangle(e.X, e.Y, 0, 0);
    this.Invalidate();
}

private void pictureBox1_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    if (stayToolStripMenuItem.Checked == true)
    {
        switch (e.Button)
        {
            case MouseButtons.Left:
            {
                rect[count] = new Rectangle(rect[count].Left, rect[count].Top, e.X - rect[count].Left, e.Y - rect[count].Top);
                pictureBox1.Invalidate();
                count++:
                break;
            }      
        }
    }
}

private void pictureBox1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
{
    if (stayToolStripMenuItem.Checked == true)
    {
        button1.Visible = true;
        button2.Visible = true;

        if (mybitmap == null)
        {
            return;
        }

        using (g = Graphics.FromImage(mybitmap))
        {
            using (Pen pen = new Pen(Color.Red, 2))
            {
                //g.Clear(Color.Transparent);
                e.Graphics.DrawRectangle(pen, rect);
                label1.Top = rect[count].Top; label1[count].Left = rect[count].Left; label1.Width = rect[count].Width;
                label1.Height = rect[count].Height;

                if (label1.TextAlign == ContentAlignment.TopLeft)
                {
                    e.Graphics.DrawString(label1.Text, label1.Font, new SolidBrush(label1.ForeColor), rect);
                    g.DrawString(label1.Text, label1.Font, new SolidBrush(label1.ForeColor), rect);
                    g.DrawRectangle(pen, rect[count]);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

How can i do this.....

Comment: What error does it give?

Comment: will somebody format the code?

Comment: @Ardman: Thanks! and you did it before i commented :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have change the code little bit. Instead of mouse move event used Mouse click event.

On using mouse move event it calls every time when mouse move on the picture box. so list rectangle count gets increased. for this i used mouse click event.

When list rectangle added in Mouse down event, it's only get the values for height and width of the rectangle (`if use (0,0,e.X,e.Y)`)and also rectangle always starts from top left corner (not able to start the rectangle point where user likes) and it's gets only `X` and `Y` values (`if use(e.X, e.Y,0,0)`)

to over come this I used the list rectangle in the mouse click event, so I get all values.

```
List<Rectangle> rectangles = new List<Rectangle>();

private void pictureBox1_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        if (stayToolStripMenuItem.Checked == true)
        {

            if (mybitmap == null)
            {
                mybitmap = new Bitmap(sz.Width, sz.Height);

            }
            rect = new Rectangle(e.X, e.Y, 0, 0);
            this.Invalidate();

        }

    }


    private void pictureBox1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        if (stayToolStripMenuItem.Checked == true)
        {
            button1.Visible = true;
            button2.Visible = true;

            if (mybitmap == null)
            {
                return;
            }


                using (g = Graphics.FromImage(mybitmap))
                {

                    using (Pen pen = new Pen(Color.Red, 2))
                    {
                        //g.Clear(Color.Transparent);


                        e.Graphics.DrawRectangle(pen, rect);
                        label1.Top = rect.Top; label1.Left = rect.Left; label1.Width = rect.Width;
                        label1.Height = rect.Height;


                        if (label1.TextAlign == ContentAlignment.TopLeft)
                        {
                            e.Graphics.DrawString(label1.Text, label1.Font, new SolidBrush(label1.ForeColor), rect);
                            g.DrawString(label1.Text, label1.Font, new SolidBrush(label1.ForeColor), rect);
                            g.DrawRectangle(pen, rect);

                        }

                    }

                }

private void pictureBox1_MouseClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {

            if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Left)

            {
                rect = new Rectangle(rect.Left, rect.Top, e.X - rect.Left, e.Y - rect.Top);
                rectangles.Add(rect);
                pictureBox1.Invalidate();
                f = 0;

            }


    }
```

What ever rectangle I draw get saved in the list rectangles and get saved when i saved the work (could see all the drawn rectangles when i opened the saved file).

Now the problem is, when I draw a new rectangle the previous one get disappeared (on run time. However this added in list rectangle).

How to display all the rectangles drawn on run time, so user can know how many rectangles drawn and where.

Answer (score 3):

You're incrementing the `count` variable after filling the `rect` array. By the time `pictureBox1_Paint` is executed, this increment has already taken place, so `rect[count]` is now a null reference, which you then try to draw :)

Also, there appears to be a compiler error in `pictureBox1_MouseDown`. The `count++` inside the `switch` statement doesn't belong to any `case` block. Put it before the `break;` statement.

I imagine your intention is something like this:

```
private void pictureBox1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
{
    if (mybitmap == null)
       return;

    using (g = Graphics.FromImage(mybitmap))
    using (Pen pen = new Pen(Color.Red, 2))
    {
        g.Clear(Color.Transparent);

        for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
        {
            // Code to draw rect[i], instead of rect[count]
        }
    }
}
```

How large is your `rect` array, by the way? Arrays do not automatically grow to accommodate your needs. You may want to look at using `List<Rectangle>` instead.

Comment: have the put the count++ before the break statement. 

If i try for loop in the paint its draw the rectangle one over the other (on same position). I like to draw the more than one rectangle in different position.

Using the above code it will draw the rectangle and if i change the position (like to draw another point) the previous rectangle get disappeared. 

How i get the more ta one rectangle....please advice

Comment: @Nivas: in your new code, you aren't incrementing `count` anywhere, so it wil keep using element 0 of the `rect` array. Thus the previous rectangle gets overwritten.

Comment: oops i missed one line. will increment the count in switch statement.

Please advice me...